# How to locate a nested element by using Selenium webdriver?

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath, webdriver

I have the following html:

```
<label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="bla-bla">
   "Value date"
   ::after
</label>
<div class="col-sm-8">
   <div class="row">
      ::before
      <div class="col-sm-2>
         <label class="control-label" for="bla-bla">
            "Priority"
            ::after
         </label>
      </div>
      ::after
   </div>
   ::after
</div>
```

I need to extract both the elements like "Value date" and the "Priority" element.
Here is my current solution:

```
elements = [f for f in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@class, 'control-label')]")]
```

It works perfectly with the elements like "Value date", but it doesn't see the "Priority" element. I see that "Priority" is nested in the "Value date" element here. Maybe, it somehow affects the way XPATH works.
I tried adding the exact class match, but without any result:

```
elements = [f for f in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@class, 'control-label') or @class = 'control-label']")]
```

Comment: You XPath looks fine. Something else is wrong.  Maybe the html you handle during execution is not like you show in this question

Answer (score 1):

Actually the XPATH was working OK. The problem was in what I was doing with the found elements next. I was extracting text by using the .text() method which doesn't always work as expected. If you experience similar problems, try using .get_attribute('innerText') and .get_attribute('textContent').